# Run a Process in IIS .NET Framework application with Windows Authenticated User (Active Directory)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, frameworks, impersonation

I'm working on a VPN with an Active Directory (LDAP) Windows Authentication.

I setup an .NET Framework C# 4.X application in IIS with ASP.NET Impersonation and Windows Authentication and it works perfecly, allowing me to connect on MSSQL DB with through the authenticated VPN user.

My goal is to run a process from my application using the authenticated user since I need to run a python script that makes some process and works with DB through an Integrated Security access.

I'm trying this way because I know that fastcgi module doesn't allow Impersonation with Python, I even made some tries but I failed. I'm trying it even because I'm trying to avoid to rewrite code in C#.

In order to test the authentication, I'm running this code:

```
var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\whoami.exe";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Receiving this output:

```
ERROR: Access is denied.
```

It seems like the network authenticated user doesn't have the permission to access the local files.

Changing the Application Pool Identity Setting to "LocalSystem" I receive this output:

```
nt authority\system
```

After that, I tried again with standard ApplicationPoolIdentity running a Python script, in order to get the user and checking before the ISS accounts have permission to run Python executable:

```
var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\mypython\\scripts\\python.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \"import getpass; print(getpass.getuser())\"";
```

This should return the username that started the process, in my case it returns "D1TBDBTB02$" that seems to be the DB Administrator account as "D1TBDBTB02" is the domain name used for SQL accounts, but unfortunately I can't log into database  through an Integrated Security access.

Just to complete my question, I want to say you that I'm not a .NET expert developer and I'm an absolutely novice with Active Directory and Windows Authentication.

I feel like what I want to do is not possible and I need to rewrite code in C# but I'm still hoping for any advice from you.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you're going to find out that impersonation just presents all sorts of issues. The better thing to do is give your application all the permissions it needs do accomplish it's job, then check the user's authorization yourself before performing work for that user.

Comment: @mason do you mean trying to implement a kind of impersonation at SQL level?

Comment: I mean any impersonation period. It will be far easier to have the user authenticate to your application, then have your application check that the user is allowed to perform the action they're attempting to perform, then have the application perform that action via its own service account rather than via impersonation.

Comment: @mason unfortunately the permissions structure of the db is very complicated and handling permissions manually is going to be very complex, probably rewrite everything in C# is the solution.